# Custom View as background for StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I need use one image below stack navigator or something like this. 
Into StackNavigator I can set backgroundColor, opacity (view style) etc. But no possibility  to set one background image or custom view component. Also if set  to each screen its not good for  screen translation.

I was try to wrap like this:

```
 <ImageBackground>
    <MyStackNavigator/>
 </ImageBackground/>
```

No results. 
Can you help me? +1 for any try

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution

Navigator:

```
const AuthStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
   LANDING: {
       screen: LandingScreen
   },
   SIGN_IN: {
       screen: SignInScreen
   },
   {
       mode: 'card',
       cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
       transitionConfig: () => ({
           containerStyle: {
               backgroundColor: 'transparent',
           }
       }),
       initialRouteName: 'LANDING',
   }
);
```

Render:

```
render() {
    return <ImageBackground
        style={{
            width: null,
            height: null,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            flex: 1,
        }}
        source={landing_background}
    >
        <AuthStackNavigator
            ref='navigator'
        />
    </ImageBackground>
}
```

Comment: I am getting error Invariant Violation: the navigation prop is missing fot this navigator, please add navigation prop and also static router

Comment: Mine is also working but 50% of previous screen is still visible underneath the current one. How to solve that